# An introductory example of simple IDE with a javascript framework

Tags: javascript, frameworks, ide

I'm trying to learn how to design a web-based IDE, but the offer on javascript frameworks is bast, and don't know what to start with. Is there any open-source elemental IDE that you know based on an actual framework, and that could teach the basics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom) is an HTML/CSS/JS editor/IDE. It uses Electron to build it into platform (Mac/Win/Linux) binaries, but all the source code this there for you to "learn how to design a web-based IDE".